# Rudin's Principle of Mathematical Analysis Problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If ${(s_n)}$ is a complex sequence, define its arithmetic means $\sigma_n$ by

$$\sigma_n = \frac{s_0 +s_1 + ... + s_n}{n+1}$$

Assume that $M < \infty, |na_n| \leq M$ for all n and 
lim ${\sigma_n = \sigma}$. Prove that lim $s_n = \sigma$.

The solution given is

If $m <n$, then

$$s_n - \sigma_n = \frac{m+1}{n-m}(\sigma_n -\sigma_m) + \frac{1}{n-m}\sum_{i=m+1}^n (s_n -s_i)$$

For these i,

$$|s_n - s_i|\leq\frac{(n-1)M}{i+1}\leq\frac{(n-m-1)M}{m+2}$$

Fix $\epsilon>1$ and associate with each n the integer m that satisfies

$$m\leq\frac{n-\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}<m+1$$

Then $(m+1)/(n-m) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $|s_n -s_i|<M\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, lim $s_n = \sigma$.

My problems is:

*Why we can choose an upper bound for n?

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd line. by $a_n$ you mean $s_n$ ? If that's the case, $s_n$ converges to 0

Comment: The question reminds me of cesaro summation

Comment: More specifically, the theorem of Cesaro-Stolz.

Comment: I second, please clarify the role of $a_n$ in relation to the other variables. 1.) At which place do you see an upper bound for $n$? A far as I see, $n$ is free and $m$ is chosen accordingly. 2.) The sequence $σ_n$ converges, so this difference is bounded.

Comment: $n-\epsilon/1+\epsilon < m+1$       
------
$n<(m+1)(1+\epsilon)+\epsilon$
------
doesn't that bound n from above?